# Symbolic link in makefile

Tags: makefile, ln

Consider the following makefile:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh

MY_DIR := $(realpath ./)

BASE_DIR := $(realpath ../..)
BASE_SRC_DIR = $(BASE_DIR)/src
BASE_INC_DIR = $(BASE_DIR)/include

HUL_DIR = $(MY_DIR)/hul

JNI_DIR = $(HUL_DIR)/jni
JNI_SRC_DIR = $(JNI_DIR)/src
JNI_INC_DIR = $(JNI_DIR)/include

dirs: $(JNI_SRC_DIR) $(JNI_INC_DIR)

$(JNI_SRC_DIR): $(JNI_DIR)
    ln -s $(BASE_SRC_DIR) $@

$(JNI_INC_DIR): $(JNI_DIR)
    ln -s $(BASE_INC_DIR) $@

$(JNI_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(JNI_DIR)
```

This makefile creates two symbolic links (`JNI_SRC_DIR` and `JNI_INC_DIR`) and sets a `JNI_DIR` as a dependency for those. All is fine except one thing: calling `make dirs` twice creates the links and then links inside those folders. I know this is the standard `ln` behaviour when symlinking folders that already exist, I just don't know of any `ln` option flag to prevent it without an error (`-n` does it but with an error). Anyway, what I'd like to change is `make` running the rules for the second time. Apparently it also follows the symlinks, but I just want it to check whether they are there:

Here's a sample output, with three calls:

```
$ make dirs
mkdir -p /Users/fratelli/Documents/hul/platform/android/hul/jni
ln -s /Users/fratelli/Documents/hul/src /Users/fratelli/Documents/hul/platform/android/hul/jni/src
ln -s /Users/fratelli/Documents/hul/include /Users/fratelli/Documents/hul/platform/android/hul/jni/include

$ make dirs
ln -s /Users/fratelli/Documents/hul/src /Users/fratelli/Documents/hul/platform/android/hul/jni/src
ln -s /Users/fratelli/Documents/hul/include /Users/fratelli/Documents/hul/platform/android/hul/jni/include

$ make dirs
make: Nothing to be done for `dirs'.
```

I'd like the second time to behave as the third, as the symlinks are already there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is that when the symlinks are created by the first `make dirs` invocation, the modification time of the directory gets updated. Because you have a dependency on the directory, that means the next time you run `make dirs`, `make` decides the targets are out of date.

You can change the dependency on `$(JNI_DIR)` to be an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) instead, like this:

```
$(JNI_SRC_DIR): | $(JNI_DIR)
    ln -s $(BASE_SRC_DIR) $@

$(JNI_INC_DIR): | $(JNI_DIR)
    ln -s $(BASE_INC_DIR) $@
```

This tells `make` to create `$(JNI_DIR)` if it doesn't exist, but it won't recreate the links if the directory has been updated.

Comment: So the directory's modification date gets altered every time I create a new directory inside?

Comment: @AndréFratelli Yep, whenever something is added or removed. (Not recursively though -- just at the top-level of the directory).